# Change space between div tags in CSS

Tags: css, html, web, space

I have a website in which I want to change the space between some elements. I don't know much about CSS. I am a newbie to it. You can see the website here.This is now on a temporary domain name : [timepasssite.hostoi.com](http://timepasssite.hostoi.com).

1. I want to reduce the space between logo and main menu1...Home..Add a Listing..I have to move it up by a small distance.
2. I also want to move the search box up in the line of the Main Menu1.
3. I want to move up the Featured Listing up near the earth's photo 4 px distance should be enough. Listing Categories move Up close to Featured Listings 2 px distance..

Can anybody guide me how to do this ?

Here are the Common.css and Style.css files..

Download [Common.css](http://timepasssite.hostoi.com/download/common.css)    [Style.css](http://timepasssite.hostoi.com/download/style.css)

Image : [image: i.stack.imgur.com/R91fy.jpg]

I can't paste the files here...I don't know how to...Please download the files for me and provide me the solution!

Comment: Please submit some code.

Comment: I dont know how to submit code so I have put hyperlinks to the Common.css and style.css

Comment: Hi Ankit I am Dipak Suryavanshi from Pune.. I can help you but you have to post some code :)

Comment: I dont know how to submit code so I have put hyperlinks to the Common.css and style.css...When I pasted the code...The lines are about 88000....They say you can only post 30000 lines here...

Comment: only paste the codes,where you have facing problem.Dont put 88000 lines.or put some sample codes.

Comment: aye aye, sir. We all at your service

Comment: -1 SO is a community to provide help with coding problems, yes, but no, SO is not a place to get your work done for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seen your css. In that `padding: 7px 10px 10px;` making space between menu and logo, and also you were mention height also.
reduce the padding and also margin-top property.

better post your codes

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking, you have to use `margin`, `padding` or in case of absolute positionning, `left, top` etc...

In order to reduce the space between your logo and your main menu, you have to reduce (or delete) the `padding-bottom` in `div#logo` css property, located on `common.css`, as this :

```
div#logo {
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

For your search bar, the css is contained inside the parent div, inline style. You'll have to override the `top` property in your css file, and giving it -50 as a value for instance.

Now you have the general idea, I think you can manage your other issues.

I strongly suggest you to use Firebug (extension for Firefox / Chrome) though.

Feel free to ask for precisions.

Answer (score 0):

make this change in common.css to remove bottom spacing of the logo -

```
div#logo {
    padding: 15px 0 0 0;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. 2, 3

I think 
You can use `margin-top` or `bottom` property

or `padding`

Answer (score 0):

In common.css, find this:

```
div#logo
{
    /*width: 185px;
    height: 75px;
    float: left;*/
    text-align: center;
    padding:15px 0px;
}
```

When two values are supplied for the `padding` attribute, they specify the top/bottom and left/right values. Therefore at the moment there is 15px of padding being applied to both the top and bottom of the logo. (See http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_padding.asp.)

Change the `padding:15px 0px;` line to `padding: 15px 0px 0px 0px;` - this will set all padding to 0 apart from the top, which stays at 15px.

You should be able to find a similar solution for your other queries: look for the container id in the HTML, then find the CSS for the id. For example, if the Featured Listing is in `<div id="featured">`, look in the CSS for `div#featured`, and edit the padding property there.

Comment: Hi there are many more featured tags here in style.css...which one should I use ?

Comment: Note that I didn't say it is the #featured tag - depends on what you find in the HTML. If it is, try the one in common.css first.